# How to make <map>-tag in Gmail work on Smartphones?

Tags: html, hyperlink, gmail, smartphone

I plan to integrate HTML in an Email in Gmail. This needs to be done because I want to send a picture that contains multiple links scattered around (on the picture are bubbles and the links should be layed over them).

For creating the links I use the HTML-tag `<map>`.
For integrating HTML in Gmail, I use the method explained in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MsMSqhMlfao).

I did all this and tested the mail on desktop computer and Smartphone. On desktop computer it works perfectly. On smartphone the picture gets displayed, but the links are not working (when I tap on the bubbles, nothing happens).
I assume that the coordinates inside the `<map>`-tag are not in the correct places when the email opens on smartphone. Does someone know a solution? Thanks a lot.

Here's how the HTML-code looks like:

```
<img src="https://blablabla.com/image.png" usemap="#image-map">

<map name="image-map">
    <area target="_blank" href="http://www.link1.com" coords="241,174,216,188,188,180,135,211,126,240,135,249,127,294,149,312,167,320,179,330,197,335,215,333,234,335,236,348,242,358,265,352,275,350,287,356,297,364,312,360,320,337,328,327,335,306,354,306,377,298,396,280,393,261,371,255,368,233,335,221,305,230,311,205,300,185,267,185" shape="poly">
    <area target="_blank" href="http://www.link2.com" coords="155,324,115,360,101,409,122,460,151,482,181,487,251,487,288,480,322,454,343,430,347,414,382,387,345,396,315,368,295,374,283,368,275,365,259,364,242,366,226,355,227,346,222,338,190,341,172,335" shape="poly">
    <area target="_blank" href="http://www.link3.com" coords="699,134,673,135,619,146,601,154,579,170,560,198,561,256,525,306,579,282,623,300,643,262,664,245,687,239,684,248,755,237,767,213,768,182,757,155" shape="poly">
    <area target="_blank" href="http://www.link4.com" coords="559,334,605,335,628,328,627,302,651,264,675,254,714,249,756,244,792,245,829,256,857,272,879,294,883,314,874,344,856,374,834,366,816,364,804,351,761,354,753,352,720,351,713,354,688,352,676,362,667,367,648,373,642,353,627,360" shape="poly">
    <area target="_blank" href="http://www.link5.com" coords="607,406,621,394,632,393,651,378,679,374,691,359,708,358,715,366,735,357,755,368,787,356,811,374,836,374,850,389,846,408,867,422,865,449,847,466,819,463,802,497,771,496,763,479,753,490,714,486,698,479,679,489,656,478,651,458,628,467,605,457,613,426" shape="poly">
</map>
```

Comment: An email is a text message. It's not a web page. The major difference is one of security. When reading an email, a user has to have complete control over it. And the developer has to have no control. Dev should not be able to conceal a link, for example. This is the main reason most style and links do not work in emails. They are just text messages with some extra stuff. But the extra stuff is standardized, so the user is in control. You want to present some cool HTML to the user? Write a nice text about it and invite them to visit it online, where it's ok for you to be in control.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and compatibility problem with Gmail in general. For standards purposes I would suggest not using image maps, as they can be buggy, aren't responsive by design, and iOS/Android often have problems interpreting them.

Here is some supporting info from Email on Acid:
https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/image-map-support-in-html-email

Specifically to your issue:

> **Potential confusion in Gmail and Outlook.com** In Gmail and
>   Outlook.com
>   the link pointer (hand) will appear even when the user
>   hovers the cursor over areas that are not defined by the image map.
>   Clicking on these areas will highlight the image in its own window and
>   can potentially confuse users which areas contain actual links.

This is probably again caused by responsiveness issues in how each client handles sizing the images (bounding content areas and what not being different widths).